# Can Deadlands Mad Scientists re-use Alchemy Formulas?

Tags: deadlands-d20

Can Formulas for Elixirs be recycled like Blueprints? The book (Deadlands: Way of New Science) doesn't say specifically, but it only mentions having to re-roll the Alchemy check to brew new batches of a previous Elixir and doesn't specify needing to re-make the Research check as well. I know being able to re-use existing Formulas would certainly save time and make Alchemy a lot more viable for frequent use, but I can't tell if it's supposed to be like that or not. Anyone have any insight into this issue?

We're playing with the the D20 version of Deadlands First ed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, formulas can be reused.

From the [Deadlands Classic Smith & Robards sourcebook](https://www.peginc.com/store/smith-robards/) (emphasis mine):

> **Reliability** 
>   Like gizmos, elixirs have a Reliability rating. Every raise on the formula roll adds +2 to the elixir’s base Reliability of
>   10. *All batches of elixir made from this formula receive this bonus.*

If a formula could only be used once, this final sentence wouldn't be meaningful.
You still need to roll *Science: Alchemy* each time you want to brew up a batch using the formula, though.

Comment: The question is about Deadlands d20, not Deadlands Classic. As such, I'm not sure that using a sourcebook from that system could possibly be correct. Heck, the sentence before the italicized one contradicts the d20 rules, as there are no raises.